# Node 4 and Node 6 behave differently with custom certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I'm trying to connect to an https server with a specific certificate. For some reason, it seems to succeed in Node 6.0.0 but fails in Node 4.4.7.

**code**

```
var fs    = require('fs');

var host = process.argv[2];       // host of the site
var certFile = process.argv[3];   // certificate from server
var ca =  fs.readFileSync(certFile, 'ascii');

var https = require('https');
https.request({ host: host, ca: ca }, function (res) {
  if (res.client.authorized) {
    console.log("node test: OK")
  } else {
    throw new Error(res.client.authorizationError)
  }
}).end()
```

**Node 6.0.0 output**

```
node test: OK
```

**Node 4.4.7 output**

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1017:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:582:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:424:38)
```

**system**

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```